# Enable physics in animation

Tags: animation, physics

I have a rigged robot and animated bones, and I want to add physics to the robot so that the robot can interact with the scene, e.g., hitting an obstacle. I set rigid body to passive and check animated, shape to mesh, but the robot still runs through the obstacle and no collision happens:
[image]

I believe there are some setting problems.

Comment: I figured out that it's the problem of the armature modifier. Solutions are available at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136846/can-i-make-animated-body-interact-with-rigid-body-object?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is mainly about the armature modifier would not feed its mesh deform results to the physics simulator, so all the simulation only happens to the original mesh.

To avoid this, it seems we need to remove the modifier, and just parenting the segmentation parts to their corresponding parts, as discussed in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136846/can-i-make-animated-body-interact-with-rigid-body-object?rq=1). I provide a simple example in the attached file: [image]

I have to say that as a beginner I made some silly mistakes in modeling and animating... But anyway thanks for letting me know.